# Expectations on Partial Mock - NullReference Exception

Tags: testing, rhino-mocks, partial-mocks

I've a problem with partial mocking using Rhino Mocks:

```
var authentication = (FormsAuthenticationService)_mocks.PartialMock(
  typeof(FormsAuthenticationService));
Expect.Call( delegate{ authentication.SetAuthCookie(null, null); }).IgnoreArguments();
```

..and I get NullReferenceException on "Expect." line..

I will just add that `FormsAuthenticationService` implements `IAuthentication`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a good reason you're trying to mock the physical class, rather than the interface? I ask this because there are 2 potential problems with mocking FormsAuthenticationService:

1. The class may not have a default
   parameterless constructor (in which
   case, you need to specify an
   overloaded method of
   mocks.PartialMock).
2. The SetAuthCookie has to be virtual. Mock frameworks typically can mock only non-sealed classes, and only the virtual members of such a class.

To get around these problems, I'd recommend mocking IAuthentication instead. Mocking interfaces doesn't have these limitations. Here's the code you'd write:

```
var authentication = _mocks.DynamicMock<IAuthentication>();
Expect.Call(() => authentication.SetAuthCookie(null, null)).IgnoreArguments();
```